# Velocity and Acceleration Polygons for Mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, mechanisms, kinematics

I need to determine the velocity and acceleration of point H using vector equations and drawing a polygon. Given data is shown. $\omega$<sub>2</sub> is 5.8 rad/s and $\phi$<sub>2</sub> is 120 degrees

[image: mechanism]

I know how I can draw both velocities and acceleration vectors on a polygon but I am clueless to how to continue after the point I reached. I found the velocity of point B by multiplying $\phi$<sub>2</sub> and the distance of the link 2.

Since VC= VB+VBC and VC=VE+VEC, I found the velocity of point C and added it to the polygon. With that at hand, I found the angular velocity of link 6 and link 3. Since point D is also on link 6, I found the velocity vector of it and placed it on the polygon. After this point, I am clueless regarding how to obtain Velocity of point H using polygons. Any help would be greatly appreciated.